# UDP - Raw Sockets - C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I need to edit headers of UDP packet (and send it with edited headers), I think I must use raw sockets.

I tried something like this:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[]{0x00,0x00};
    string ip = "SomeIP"

    Socket sk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Raw);
    sk.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
    sk.SendTo(new byte[] { buffer }, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip),2017));
```

But I still can't edit header :(

Answer (score 0):

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00 };
        string ip = "SomeIP";
        // Set Socket Type to 'Dgram' for connectionless and UDP since your working with UDP 
        Socket sk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sk.SendTo(buffer, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 2017));
```